# Django statelessness?

Tags: python, django

I'm just wondering if Django was designed to be a fully **stateless** framework?

It seems to encourage statelessness and external storage mechanisms (databases and caches) but I'm wondering if it is possible to store some things in the server's memory while my app is in develpoment and runs via `manage.py runserver`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible. But if you are writing a web application you probably won't want to do that because of threading issues.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by "store things in the server's memory." It also depends on the type of data. If you can, you're better off storing "global data" in a database or in the file system somewhere. Unless it is needed *every request* it doesn't really make sense to store it in the Django instance itself. You'll need to implement some form of locking to prevent race conditions, but you'd need to worry about race conditions if you stored everything on the server object anyway.

Of course, if you're talking about user-by-user data, Django does support [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/). Or, and this is another perfectly good option if you're willing to make the user save the data, [cookies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to maintain state in a django app on a per-user basis is `request.session` (see [django sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)) which is a dictionary you can use to remember things about the current user.

For Application-wide state you should use the a persistent datastore (database or key/value store)

example view for sessions:

```
def my_view(request):
    pages_viewed = request.session.get('pages_viewed', 1) + 1
    request.session['pages_viewed'] = pages_viewed

    ...
```

If you wanted to maintain local variables on a per app-instance basis you can just define module level variables like so

```
# number of times my_view has been served since by this server 
# instance since the last restart
served_since_restart = 0

def my_view(request):
    served_since_restart += 1
    ...
```

If you wanted to maintain some server state across ALL app servers (like total number of pages viewed **EVER**) you should probably use a persistent key/value store like redis, memcachedb, or riak. There is a decent comparison of all these options here: http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

You can do it with redis (via [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)) like so (assuming your redis server is at "127.0.0.1" (localhost) and it's port 6379 (the default):

```
import redis

def my_view(request):
    r = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port="6379")
    served = r.get('pages_served_all_time', 0)
    served += 1
    r.set('pages_served_all_time', served)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [LocMemCache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) cache backend that stores data in-process. You can use it with sessions (but with great care: this cache is not cross-process so you will have to use single process for deployment because it will not be guaranteed that subsequent requests will be handled by the same process otherwise). Global variables may also work (use threadlocals if they shouldn't be shared for all process threads; the warning about cross-process communication also applies here).

By the way, what's wrong with external storage? External storage provides easy cross-process data sharing and other features (like memory limiting algorithms for cache or persistance with databases).